# Sockets not able to receive message from the server

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, websocket, c#-3.0

I am trying to connect to a application using sockets.

The application communicates using port 6100.
I am am able to send the messages to the application but not able to receive any message.

This is my code please let me know if i am doing anything wrong.

```
public void Connect2(string host, int port, string cmd)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[10024];
    IPAddress[] IPs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);

    Socket s = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
    SocketType.Stream,
    ProtocolType.Tcp);
    s.SendTimeout = 100;
Console.WriteLine("Establishing Connection to {0}",
    host);
    try
    {
        s.Connect(IPs[0], port);
    }

    catch (Exception e)
    {

        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }



    byte[] sendBites = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd);
    int bytesSent = s.Send(sendBites);
    int bytesRec = s.Receive(bytes);
    s.ReceiveFrom(bytes, ref tmpRemote);
    MessageBox.Show(s.ReceiveBufferSize.ToString());
    MessageBox.Show(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));
    s.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
    s.Close();

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code works fine.

```
     public string SocketSendReceive(string server, int port, string cmd)
    {
        byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[1024];
        string host = "127.0.0.1";
        TcpClient tcpClient = new TcpClient();
        try
        {
            tcpClient.Connect(host, 6100);
        }
        catch (SocketException /*e*/)
        {
            tcpClient = null;
        }


        if (tcpClient != null && tcpClient.Connected)
        {

            tcpClient.Client.Send(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(cmd));
            tcpClient.Client.Receive(recvBuffer);
            //    port = Convert.ToInt16(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(recvBuffer).Substring(2));
            tcpClient.Close();

        }

        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBuffer, 0, recvBuffer.Length);
    }
```

Comment: This code is broken. It fails to check the return value from `Receive` which tells you how many bytes have been placed in the buffer. TCP is streams of bytes. If you want "messaging", it's up to you to implement message framing yourself on top of TCP, or to move to a higher level abstraction that already offers messaging.

Answer (score 0):

First when the Connect failes, you're still trying to send/receive data. Put the send and receive inside the try/catch.

---

I can see that you're calling receive twice:

```
int bytesRec = s.Receive(bytes);
s.ReceiveFrom(bytes, ref tmpRemote);
```

What probably happens is:

- You are sending a command
- You are waiting for a response "**int bytesRec = s.Receive(bytes);**"
- Then again you are waiting for more data.. "**s.ReceiveFrom(bytes, ref tmpRemote);**"

**But probably the server won't send additional data, so you are waiting "forever"**

Try again removing the `s.ReceiveFrom(bytes, ref tmpRemote);`

---

The `Socket.ReceiveFrom()` is usually used for receiving UDP broadcasts.

Comment: I have changed the code but still my application hangs and i do not get any error message.

Comment: try
            {
                s.Connect(IPs[0], port);
                byte[] sendBites = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(cmd);
                int bytesSent = s.Send(sendBites);
                int bytesRec = 0;
                do
                {
                    bytesRec = s.Receive(bytes, bytes.Length, 0);
                    
                }
                while (bytesRec > 0);

            }


            catch (Exception e)
            {

               MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }